# Phanomjs not properly capturing screenshot of a web page

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I am testing phantom.js for creating screenshots from a web page at my local end.

This is how HTML is rendering in localhost - [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r9YR.jpg)

But on creating PDF from code, width is not setting properly in PDF, i.e. some text gets cut as shown below.

Following is the code I tried -

```
var url = 'http://localhost:5656';
page.open(url);

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    var pdfName = 'screen';
    page.render(pdfName + ".pdf");
    var height = page.evaluate(function() { return document.body.offsetHeight }),
        width = page.evaluate(function() { return document.body.offsetWidth });
    console.log(height,width);  
};
```

I also tried these two properties but getting same result -

```
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, width: 1286};
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768};
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Output I am getting** - PDF image I am getting][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpx6D.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the working code:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:5656';
page.open(url);

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    //page.viewportSize = { width: 1400, height: 1200 };
    page.paperSize = {format: 'A4'};
    var pdfName = 'screen';
    page.render(pdfName + ".pdf");
    var height = page.evaluate(function() { return document.body.offsetHeight }),
        width = page.evaluate(function() { return document.body.offsetWidth });
    console.log(height,width);  
};
```

As you can see, following is the line that performed the magic for me -

```
page.paperSize = {format: 'A4'};
```